# CSS | grid-auto-columns: min-content | not working in IOS 10.3.3

Tags: ios, css, safari, css-grid

Is there any substitution for this, or should I revert back to floats and wait until support arrives?

```
.grid_root {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 1px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: min-content;
}
```

Sample (use full screen preview in phone):
https://plnkr.co/edit/c6Znq3rtEfQK0Ky1wugt?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using webkit prefixes. Works on Safari in my iPad.

```
.grid_root {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 1px;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: -webkit-min-content; /* new */
  grid-auto-columns: min-content;
}
```

[revised demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/9VfEAbJcCllsbarIfuo7?p=preview)